# Sql recursive query error

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sorting, group-by, recursive-query

```
WITH BomTree (
    ITEMNO
    ,[DESC]
    ,BOMNO
    ,BUILDQTY
    ,UNIT
    ,COMPONENT
    ,[Comp Desc]
    ,[Comp-Qty]
    ,COMPBOMNO
    ,Depth
    )
AS (
    SELECT bomh.ITEMNO
        ,itm1.DESC]
        ,bomh.BOMNO
        ,bomh.BUILDQTY
        ,bomh.UNIT
        ,bomd.COMPONENT
        ,itm.[DESC] [Comp Desc]
        ,bomd.QTY [Comp-Qty]
        ,bomd.COMPBOMNO
        ,0 AS Depth
    FROM ICBOMH bomh
    INNER JOIN ICBOMD bomd ON bomh.BOMNO = bomd.BOMNO
        AND bomh.ITEMNO = bomd.ITEMNO
    INNER JOIN ICITEM itm1 ON bomd.ITEMNO = itm1.ITEMNO
    INNER JOIN ICITEM itm ON bomd.COMPONENT = itm.ITEMNO
    WHERE bomd.BOMNO = '01'
        AND bomd.ITEMNO = '300060397'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT bomh.ITEMNO
        ,itm1.DESC]
        ,bomh.BOMNO
        ,bomh.BUILDQTY
        ,bomh.UNIT
        ,bomd.COMPONENT
        ,itm.[DESC] [Comp Desc]
        ,(t.[Comp-Qty] * bomd.QTY) AS [Comp-Qty]
        ,bomd.COMPBOMNO
        ,t.Depth + 1 AS Depth
    FROM ICBOMH bomh
    INNER JOIN ICBOMD bomd ON bomh.BOMNO = bomd.BOMNO
        AND bomh.ITEMNO = bomd.ITEMNO
    INNER JOIN ICITEM itm1 ON bomd.ITEMNO = itm1.ITEMNO
    INNER JOIN ICITEM itm ON bomd.COMPONENT = itm.ITEMNO
    INNER JOIN BomTree AS t ON bomd.ITEMNO = t.COMPONENT
    )
SELECT ITEMNO
    ,[DESC]
    ,BOMNO
    ,BUILDQTY
    ,UNIT
    ,COMPONENT
    ,[Comp Desc]
    ,[Comp-Qty]
    ,COMPBOMNO
    ,Depth
FROM BomTree
GROUP BY ITEMNO
    ,[DESC]
    ,BOMNO
    ,BUILDQTY
    ,UNIT
    ,COMPONENT
    ,[Comp Desc]
    ,[Comp-Qty]
    ,COMPBOMNO
    ,Depth;
```

> error:Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in
>   column "Comp-Qty" of recursive query "BomTree".

Comment: Could you please explain in your own words what you want your code to do, and what it's actually doing, and anything else you've already tried to resolve the issue? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Thank you,

Comment: What the error means is: your `Comp-Qty` has a data type mismatch.

Comment: Not sure about the error, but maybe it's value overflow, since you are multiplying, not adding. Did you mean `(t.[Comp-Qty]  +  bomd.QTY) AS [Comp-Qty]`?

Comment: `GROUP BY` on all result columns is much better written using `DISTINCT`.

Comment: What is the datatype of your `bomd.QTY` column?

Comment: maybe type mismatch for result of `,bomd.QTY [Comp-Qty]` of first select statement and `,(t.[Comp-Qty] * bomd.QTY) AS [Comp-Qty]` of second select statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this error means there is mismatch in datatype between the same columns in two union  queries. In order to fix this you could rewrite your query something like this:

```
WITH BomTree 
AS (
    SELECT bomh.ITEMNO
        ,itm1.[DESC]
        ,bomh.BOMNO
        ,bomh.BUILDQTY
        ,bomh.UNIT
        ,bomd.COMPONENT
        ,itm.[DESC] [Comp Desc]
        ,cast(bomd.QTY as int) [Comp-Qty]  --cast as integer 
        ,bomd.COMPBOMNO
        ,0 AS Depth
    FROM ICBOMH bomh
    INNER JOIN ICBOMD bomd ON bomh.BOMNO = bomd.BOMNO
        AND bomh.ITEMNO = bomd.ITEMNO
    INNER JOIN ICITEM itm1 ON bomd.ITEMNO = itm1.ITEMNO
    INNER JOIN ICITEM itm ON bomd.COMPONENT = itm.ITEMNO
    WHERE bomd.BOMNO = '01'
        AND bomd.ITEMNO = '300060397'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT bomh.ITEMNO
        ,itm1.DESC]
        ,bomh.BOMNO
        ,bomh.BUILDQTY
        ,bomh.UNIT
        ,bomd.COMPONENT
        ,itm.[DESC] [Comp Desc]
        ,cast((t.[Comp-Qty] * bomd.QTY) as int)  AS [Comp-Qty] --cast as integer 
        ,bomd.COMPBOMNO
        ,t.Depth + 1 AS Depth
    FROM ICBOMH bomh
    INNER JOIN ICBOMD bomd ON bomh.BOMNO = bomd.BOMNO
        AND bomh.ITEMNO = bomd.ITEMNO
    INNER JOIN ICITEM itm1 ON bomd.ITEMNO = itm1.ITEMNO
    INNER JOIN ICITEM itm ON bomd.COMPONENT = itm.ITEMNO
    INNER JOIN BomTree AS t ON bomd.ITEMNO = t.COMPONENT
    )
SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNO
    ,[DESC]
    ,BOMNO
    ,BUILDQTY
    ,UNIT
    ,COMPONENT
    ,[Comp Desc]
    ,[Comp-Qty]
    ,COMPBOMNO
    ,Depth
FROM BomTree;
```